# Sort array in descending order but keep NaNs at the end

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have an array:

`Data = [10 20 30 50 40 60 NaN NaN 70 80; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];`

The first row represents the data and the second one contains the indices for the first row.

I want to arrange the first row in descending order, but with the correct indices.

Therefore, my output should be like

```
N_Data = [80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 NaN NaN; 10 9 6 4 5 3 2 1 8 7];
```

I don't really care about the `NaNs` so it is ok to eliminate them from the array `N_Data`

Comment: `[sortedData, sortedIndices] = sort(Data(1,:)); N_Data = [sortedData; sortedIndices];`

Comment: If it was just to arrange the data from first row in descending order, it would have been very easy, but I don't understand how can I arrange the indices in the second row accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find two options, inspired by [**this answers**](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35301-sorting-nan) applied for your case:

```
%// Option 1
Data = [10 20 30 50 40 60 NaN NaN 70 80; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

Data(isnan(Data)) = -Inf;
N_Data = sortrows(Data.',-1).'
N_Data(isinf(N_Data)) = NaN

%// Option 2
Data = [10 20 30 50 40 60 NaN NaN 70 80; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

[sortedData, sortedIndices] = sort(Data(1,:),'descend')
N_Data = [sortedData; sortedIndices]
mask = isnan(sortedData)
N_Data = [ N_Data( :,~mask), N_Data( :, mask) ]
```

---

```
N_Data =

    80    70    60    50    40    30    20    10   NaN   NaN
    10     9     6     4     5     3     2     1     7     8
```

If you don't care about the NaNs, the options can be shortened to:

```
%// Option 1
Data(isnan(Data)) = -Inf;
N_Data = sortrows(Data.',-1).'
N_Data(:,isinf(N_Data(1,:))) = []

%// Option 2
[sortedData, sortedIndices] = sort(Data(1,:),'descend')
N_Data = [sortedData; sortedIndices]
N_Data = N_Data( :,~isnan(sortedData) )
```

Explanation:

```
%// N_Data = N_Data( :,~isnan(sortedData) )
x = isnan(sortedData) %// creates logical mask, where NaNs exist
y = ~x %// negates mask, to mask values which are not Nan
N_Data = N_Data( :,y ) %// selects all rows and masked columns without NaN
```

---

```
N_Data =

    80    70    60    50    40    30    20    10
    10     9     6     4     5     3     2     1
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how exactly does this line work? `N_Data = [ N_Data( :,~isnan(sortedData))`

Answer (score 3):

You can just sort the *negative* of your data in the default ascending order which will automatically place the `NaN` values at the end. You can then negate the result to get the original values

```
result = -sortrows(-Data.').'
%   80    70    60    50    40    30    20    10   NaN   NaN
%   10     9     6     4     5     3     2     1     8     7
```

And if you want to remove `NaN` values

```
result = result(:, any(isnan(result), 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sortrows(Data.',-1).'`.

It sorts rows and you want columns sorted, hence the `.'`. The `-1` option is for descending order.

Comment: It does not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The `NaNs` are causing the problem. They are listed first and I don't want them

Comment: @thewaywewalk OP wrote: "I don't really care about the `NaNs` so it is ok to eliminate them from the array `N_Data`". This might as well mean it is ok to let them be. It turns out they do cause a problem, but that was not specified in the question.

Comment: And it was what OP wanted. OP just wanted two separate things (sortrows and NaN removal). You (@thewaywewalk) just assumed the question was only about the NaN removal.

Comment: I agree, it was not well stated in the question. You should use the correct [**`.'` transpose operator**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/973/common-mistakes-and-errors/5141/the-transpose-operators#t=201701121546211982894) though.

Comment: Agreed. I did think of it, but I used it twice, so complex conjugation goes out, right?